# assert a value is present in a listview using Selenium webdriver

Tags: listview, selenium-webdriver, record, listviewitem

I am just working on a form that I need to validate that a new record exist in a listview. This list view contains over 200 records, so I will have to make a search for a particular value and assert that it is present.

The issue is that I have not worked with Listview before and asserting a value is present under a column seems clumsy. I will appreciate if anybody can offer good advice on how to work with a listview.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML you can try the following:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>

String lookingFor = "Item2";
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for(WebElement ele: allElements ) {
        if(ele.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(lookingFor)) {
           System.out.println("Got it");
        }
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please post some code and I will review it.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. My project is testing a dynamic value. This can test against static value. What I want is that it should search for the value (text), an example: "ken4ward", under a particular column in the Listview, and assert that it exists.

Comment: If you loop over all of the listview elements, it will be extremely slow.  Please don't do that when it can be done with a single selector.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using xpath.

I'm assuming your listview is built similar to a table, so you can take this and modify it as you see fit, but it should give you a good start.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[<column #> - 1][contains(., '<text here>')]"));
```

Say, you are looking in column 3 for the text 'ken4ward':

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[2][contains(., 'ken4ward')]"));
```

I am doing "column # - 1" because xpath indexes are 0 based, and, generally speaking, we don't count columns starting with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Hamcrest assertions `assertThat(selenium.findElement(LocatorOfListView)).getText(),
                is(equalTo(ParticularItemYouWantToFind)));`

```
.getText()
```

will store all values of the list view, the rest explains itself